# determine the count of a list variable of type "var"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to set the `ViewBag.Job_CoId2` just if the `CoId2` has a record, but I get below error in third line!

```
  SelectList Job_CoId = 
      new SelectList(db.COM_Company.OrderBy(a => a.COM_Name), "COM_ID", "COM_Name");
  var CoId2 = db.Job_CoId2
      .Where(a => a.IDMainCo == Job_CoId.First().Value);
  if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0)
         ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = 
             new SelectList(CoId2.OrderBy(a => a.rank), "ID", "Name");
```

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue appears to be that you need a **List** of `SelectListItems` (such as `List<SelectListItem>`) not a `SelectList`.

```
//you may need to call .ToString() on non varchar columns such as your ID
 List<SelectListItem> Job_CoId = db.COM_Company.OrderBy(a => a.COM_Name)
  .Select(a=>new SelectListItem{Name = a.COM_Name, Value = a.COM_ID}).ToList();

   //make sure Job_CoId has something else call .First() will fail
   var CoId2 = db.Job_CoId2.Where(a => a.IDMainCo == Job_CoId.First().Value);
   if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0){
     //we actually need a List<SelectListItem> for the view
     ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = CoId2.OrderBy(a => a.rank)
     .Select(r => new SelectListItem { Name = r.Name, Value = r.Id}).ToList();
   }
   else{
       //null ref exception if you try and call this and nothing here
       ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
   }
```

Now, I think we can clean this up as we can combine some of your calls in the second drop down list.  Also, be aware that SelectListItem casts both Name and Value to strings, so you may need to cast back to the primitive type in EF for the second query.

```
List<SelectListItem> Job_CoId = db.COM_Company.OrderBy(a => a.COM_Name)
      .Select(a=>new SelectListItem{Name = a.COM_Name, Value = a.COM_ID.ToString()}).ToList();
if(Job_CoId.Any()){
    //ID will be a string coming out of select list.
    //may need to recast to an int for DB comparisons
    var intId = int.Parse(Job_CoId.First().Value);
    ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = db.Job_CoId2.Where(a => a.IDMainCo == intId)
      .OrderBy(a => a.rank)
      .Select(r => new SelectListItem { Name = r.Name, Value = r.Id}).ToList();    
}else{
    ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
}
```

Comment: I get the error in second line. `if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0)`. I can not even determine if it returns a record or not.

Comment: Now that I see that Job_CoId is, you need to apply the same fix to it as I proposed in the second part of your function.  Again, you need a `List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Also, you probably want a check on if Job_CoId has any values as calling `.First()` on this collection in the next line will throw an exception if there are no matching values

Comment: I used your code and I got the error again. My problem is this part : `if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0)` . The error occures when I want to count the records. (not the other parts of my code!)

Comment: That is because you are trying to count something that is not Enumerable if you are using `SelectList`.  I've added a cleaned up version that should function as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

make the CoId2 to .TOLIST():'

```
  var Job_CoId = db.COM_Company.Select(x=>x.COM_ID).ToList();
  var CoId2 = db.Job_CoId2.Where(a => a.IDMainCo == Job_CoId.First().Value);
   if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0)
     ViewBag.Job_CoId2 = new SelectList(CoId2.OrderBy(a => a.rank).ToList(), "ID","Name");
```

Comment: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: ok try one the: remove .ToList from first query and place it to nect line : check the edited answer

Comment: I used `if ((CoId2.ToList.Count()) > 0)` and I got the error again!

Comment: tell me one thing . what is Job_CoId.First().?

Comment: It's another list. I updated my question. I appriciate  your help.

Comment: I used your code but the error remains. the error occures in `if ((CoId2.Count()) > 0)`. I dont know how should I count it.

Comment: if ((CoId2.ToList().Count()) > 0)